# How can I create PDF using XSL and Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I believe I will have to use an XSLFO stylesheet document for the XMLs I use to convert to PDF.  And then I would need to use the Transform API of Java to convert XML to PDF.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you google? 
Asking for code samples will usually get you flames

Answer (score 1):

The XML data can be read using a parser and directly be converted to PDF (XML -> PDF) using a library like iText instead of using complex conversions (XML -> XSLT -> XSLFO -> PDF).

Comment: I wish you would elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apache FOP.  We use this at work and it's worked well for us.  http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html